# Better way to implement authentication in microservice architecture using vert.x

Tags: authentication, oauth, microservices, vert.x

Someone have idea how to implement authentication and autorization process in vert.x microservice architecture thru API Gateway service and standalone user service, where it has own custom Auth provider? Should it use shared data (hazelcast map) to store some user information like name, roles by token or something else? I,m breaking mind..

Comment: What have you found so far? Any researching, googling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a user service, I wanted all authentication and authorization operations to be performed through it.
In the end, I did this:

```
jdbcAuth.rxAuthenticate(authInfo)
            .map(user -> user.principal().getString("username"))
            .flatMap(username -> roleRepository.findByUsername(username).map(roles -> {
                JWTOptions jwtOptions = new JWTOptions().setAlgorithm("RS256");
                roles.forEach(jwtOptions::addPermission);
                LOGGER.info("Token successfully created");
                String token = jwtAuth.generateToken(new JsonObject().put("username", username), jwtOptions);
                return new JsonObject().put("accessToken", token).put("tokenType", "Bearer");
            }))
            .subscribe(SingleHelper.toObserver(handler));
```

1. For user authentication I use JDBCAuth (and solt hash generation for new user creation)
2. If there is such user we are getting roles, generate a token with optional claims like "username" and JWTOptions with perrmissions.
3. Putting into request header Authorization: Bearer --token--
4. On other microservices we put global JWTAuth handler with pulicKey like:

   ```
   JWTAuthHandler.create(JWTAuth.create(vertx.getDelegate(), new JWTAuthOptions().addPubSecKey(new PubSecKeyOptions()
           .setAlgorithm("RS256")
           .setPublicKey(<PUBLIC_KEY>))));
   ```
5. This handler sets the user to the context, and we can get it through context.user () and check the permissions. By the way, we can put this handler along with the addAuthority() method on the route for access checking.

Answer (score 0):

As part of a microservices architecture, I'd not implement the authentication directly in my vert.x microservice but I'd go through with an API management gateway like [tyk](https://tyk.io/) or [kong](https://konghq.com/) for example.

Then I'd only check the permissions of the user over the data in my microservice using any database you want.

You can also dig [this track](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-common/java/) if you really want to handle authentication directly in your microservice.

Comment: I don't know about this products. I will check it. Thanks)

Comment: @luckyshroom There's plenty of api management gateway solutions (and you can even implement an authentication gateway by yourself) but the point is to think "SoC" (Separation of Concerns) when you need to go through a microservices architecture. The oauth or JWT authentication part is probably not the real concern of your service whereas checking the permissions before doing an action is (it's not the same thing).

Comment: For the same reason, I think it's better to going through a servicemesh like Istio to deal with issues of resiliency (retry strategies, circuit breaker, etc), tracing and monitoring instead of doing that directly in your service implementation.